# CHMOD 0777, but Wordpress still not able to write files/folders

Tags: apache, vps

The day before yesterday I ordered my own VPS. But now I have problems with Wordpress, Wordpress is not able to create a .htaccess by itself, not able to write to it and plugins aren't able to create files/folders.

Support hadn't the time for me, so since yesterday I'm looking for a solution by myself, with no luck.

If I change the CHMOD of all folders and files to 777 or 755, I still cannot write files/folders. So I looked further, the owner/group of my www folder on the vps is webapps:apache. I tried to change webapps to the user "root", "nobody", "apache" and "admin". But nothing worked.

When I activate the debug plugin I get these errors on the front-end: Warning: parse_ini_file() [function.parse-ini-file]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/lib/php.ini) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/:.../php/) in .../class.krumo.php on line 284

Does somebody else has another possible solution?

Comment: What kind of server is it? Evidence suggests Linux or BSD but... CentOS, Debian, what?

Comment: This question isn't WordPress related; it's server admin. See http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3):

This really isn't a Wordpress issue. That said, the key error is "`open_basedir` restriction in effect." If you're running your own VPS, you need to learn to configure it.

`open_basedir` restrictions keep scripts in one directory from being able to affect scripts in another directory, which is an important security feature. If one accounts gets hacked, open_basedir prevents the infection from spreading to another account.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths and modify open_basedir configs http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

With open base configured, you should be able to go back to 755 permissions folder and the standard WP permissions scheme: [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But open_basedir isn't working for me :( Check out: http://sexydameslingerie.nl/. I did add the new line at open_basedir but I'm still not able to write to .htaccess or any other file/directory. Even when I totally disable open_basedir with "none" it's still not working :( :(

Comment: Problem is solved. Someone suggested me to install suPHP and all problems are solved! Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: "Thanks for your help, anyway." Well, not so fast. Installing suPHP was peripheral to the issues at hand. If you're running your own VPS, you need to learn server admin.

Comment: You're probably right. Cause today I found out that I was having problems with phpmyadmin after installing suPHP. So I reinstalled the complete VPS... I sent a ticket to CloudVPS, and I think I just need to wait till tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's strange - because if you had your folders chmodded as 777, it means that all user/groups will have write permission to it. So my primary thinking is that you are not chmodding the appropriate directory. It could be that some plugins has altered the locations of the upload directory etc.

Install WP Debug plugin and check out the debug messages first, take a not of which folder it is trying to write to and then chmod once again

Good luck

Comment: I get different errors. When I activate the debug plugin I get these errors on the front-end:
Warning: parse_ini_file() [function.parse-ini-file]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/lib/php.ini) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/:.../php/) in .../class.krumo.php on line 284

Comment: When I try to activate another plugin I get these errors in the back-end:

Warning: parse_ini_file(/usr/local/lib/php.ini) [function.parse-ini-file]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in [...]/class.krumo.php on line 284
When I try to activate a plugin:
Uploads folder [...]/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport_history must be writable

Comment: So it does seems it has something to do with Apache, that's my opinion. But I don't know what ... :(

Comment: I think your hosting has the following php.ini settings turned off 

"open_basedir"

please check http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir